# How to get a C++ perror(errno) message without printing it.

Tags: c++, stream

If you use 'perror(errno)' it automatically prints the error to the standard error output-stream. Is there a way to get the value that would be printed without printing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use one of the [`strerror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror.html) functions for that. They'll retrieve the error message without printing it.